# Visual Studio 2017 color changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vs-color-theme-editor

I am trying to change colors of my VS. I am using [Color Theme Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor).
And I am struggling to find few option which controls View windows background.
How do you change that background which is circled in images?
First is Solution Explorer window, and second Team Explorer.

[image: Solution Explorer window]

[image]

Comment: Open the generated style file in a text editor, and you should see a lot of weird names with colors. Many names are not reflected in Color Theme Editor, but do control how VS renders. You have to set magic numbers to such, and then see which takes effect. Very boring process, but I did it once for DockPanel Suite. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If any one stumbles upon this, when you click `Customize colors` under `Tools` you need to switch to `Show all elements` view. There you need to find `TreeView` category. And there are all options to manipulate `Solution Explorer` and some part of `Team Explorer`.